# Is it possible to re-show the last opened Form when the MIDlet was paused?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp, midlet, lwuit-form

The application is running , the user is making some `TextField` editing. Then a call is received , so the `MIDlet` enters the `paused` state. When the conversation is finished then the application is restarted , the `startApp()` method of the `MIDlet` is called and the `main` `Form` of the application is shown !

So how to dismiss this default behaviour so that the last opened `Form` with all the modifications are kept ?

Comment: Display the current Form in PauseApp()

Comment: That doesn't work : I create in the midlet a `public static com.sun.lwuit.Form lastForm = null;` and in the constructor of a Form I make : `myMidlet.lastForm = this;`. Then in the `pauseApp()` I code : `lastForm.showBack();` but the main Form is always shown ! The last Form is shown just a fraction of a second but the main Form is then opened !

Comment: did you test this with plain lcdui forms instead of ones provided by lwuit?

Comment: 99% of my Forms are lwuit Forms , there is just one canvas in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a `static` `Form` in the `MIDlet` class :

```
public static Form lastForm = null;
```

Then I set it to the actual Form in every Form of my `project` :

```
if (!myMidlet.lastCanvas.isEmpty())
    myMidlet.lastCanvas.clear();    
myMidlet.lastForm = this;
```

Then in the `startApp()` I wrote :

```
public void startApp() {
        ...
        if (lastForm != null)
            lastForm.showBack();
        else
        {
            new MainForm(this).show();
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT :**

For the canvas :

In the `MIDlet` class :

```
public static Hashtable lastCanvas = new Hashtable();
```

In the `canvas` class ( constructor ) :

```
if (myMidlet.lastForm != null)
    myMidlet.lastForm = null;

if (!myMidlet.lastCanvas.isEmpty())
    myMidlet.lastCanvas.clear();

myMidlet.lastCanvas.put(new String("Form"), this);
```

And in the `startApp()` :

```
public void startApp() {
        VKBImplementationFactory.init();
        Display.init(this);
        if (lastForm != null)
            lastForm.showBack();
        else if (!lastCanvas.isEmpty())
        {
            javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent((Canvas)lastCanvas.get(new String("Form")));
        }
        else
            new MainForm(this).show();
    }
```

I think this approach of using a `HashTable` will work even for any `lcdui` Form.

Comment: if you replace form with displayable it will cover canvas as well: `public static Displayable lastDisplayable = null; //...` - assuming that `showBack` and `show` methods are applicable to Displayable

Comment: unfortunately these methods are only relevant to LWUIT. See my answer edit for the canvas , perhaps the `lcdui` Form can also be applied to the new method.

Answer (score 1):

In LWUIT, I use this

```
import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
......
......
......

public void startApp() {
    if (Display.isInitialized()) {
        if (Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {
            Display.getInstance().getCurrent().showBack();
        }
    } else {
        //your normal initialization code.
    }
}
```